# Play animations from Cocos Studio in sequence in cocos2d-js

Tags: cocos2d-x-3.0, cocos2d-js

I have created animations ( attack, dropWeapon, run, retreat ) in Cocos Studio for Cocos2d-js and I can play that in code via

```
sprite = ccs.load( "res/solder.json" );
this.addChild( sprite.node );
sprite.node.runAction( sprite.action );
sprite.action.play( "attack", false ); // false means do not repeat  / loop
```

How can I play animations one after another in Sequence ?
I have code when I create animation in code but not in Cocos Studio.

Answer (score 0):

you can write a function with the list of animations as parameters and check
isComplete() for previous animation to start the next one

Answer (score 0):

You can create a sequence of actions using cc.Sequence

```
var actionArray = [action1, action2, action3];
var seq = new cc.Sequence(actionArray);
sprite.runAction(seq);
```

Add all the actions to an array, and create a new action, where all of these actions would run in a sequence